# python regex - extracting digits from string with numbers and characters

Tags: python, regex

I have data that has strings like 'ms2p5', 'ms3', 'ms10' for which I need to extract the digits as convert to numbers as follows.

```
'ms2p5' => 2.5
'ms3' => 3
'ms10' => 10
```

I tried the below regex and it is able to get the match. One issue is with values having a character in the middle of the extracted string like '2p5'. What is the right approach to have a generic function that handles all these cases well while converting them into numeric values?

```
import re
re.search(r'\d+[p]*\d*', str).group()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the regex you currently have?

Comment: What about `".".join(re.findall(r'\d+', string))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.join` with `re.findall`:

```
los = ['ms2p5', 'ms3', 'ms10']
print([float('.'.join(re.findall('\d+', i))) for i in los])
```

Output:

```
[2.5, 3.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extraction function that searched for a numeric value (with or without `p` for a decimal point, replaced the `p` with a `.` and then converted to float. For example:

```
import re

def extract_num(s):
    return float(re.search(r'\d+p?\d*', s).group().replace('p', '.'))

strs = ['ms2p5', 'ms3', 'ms10']
print([extract_num(s) for s in strs])
```

Output:

```
[2.5, 3.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings all follow the examples you provide, I'd probably just do:

```
x = 'ms2p5'
float(x[2:].replace('p', '.'))
```